# Throwing HttpResponseException causes an unhandled exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm working my way through a tutorial in "Practial ASP.NET Web API" by Badrinarayanan Lakshmiraghavan.

I think it is suggesting that some exceptions can be used to send out a "404 - Not Found " type thing back to the browser. However I am just getting the regular program "crash" (error message pops up).

I must have missed something. Can anyone tell me what it might be? (there are lots of similar questions here but I cant find one for this case).

I get...

```
"HttpResponseException was unhandled by user code"
```

URL used...

`http://localhost:63694/api/employees/12344`

Code...

```
public class EmployeesController : ApiController
{
    private static IList<Employee> list = new List<Employee>()
    {
        new Employee() {
        Id = 12347, FirstName = "Joseph", LastName = "Law"}
    };


    // GET api/employees
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Get()
    {
        return list;
    }

    // GET api/employees/12345
    public Employee Get(int id)
    {
        var employee = list.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);

        if (employee == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        return employee;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the entire line where you declare your controller class.

Comment: @G. Stoynev, what do you mean. All controller class is above. Just namespace, using, and employee definition missing. Which of these do you need?

Comment: I must have missed that somehow :-) In that case - the exception should be converted to HttpMessage when it reaches the end of the pipeline.

Comment: Hi, I'm having a similar issue, except my code is not contained in a Web API Controller. I created an HttpModule which inherits from `IHttpModule`. Hence, `Request.CreateResponse()` is not available. Does anyone know how can I send an `HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)` to the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebApi should handle the exception and return the status code contained in it. It is possible that you are running this not in `ApiController`-derived controller, but one derived from `Controller`.

You're better off returning HttpResponseMessage with contents of your Employee type. In that case you have better controll over the status code, like this:

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Notfound);
return response

// GET api/employees/12345
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    var employee = list.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);

    if (employee == null)
    {
        response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
    else
    {
        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, employee);
    }

    return response;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this seems like a more logical way of doing it - returning somethign, rather than raising an exception.

Comment: For consistency, I believe that the condition if (employee == null) should create the response like so: response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Employee not found");

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you could do what the other 2 users posted, but the way you are doing it is correct.

Web API Exception Handling: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling

However, if you run in Debug mode in visual studio, VS will warn you about unhandled exceptions and such. However, if you do not run in debug mode or if you deploy to IIS, the behavior will work properly and a 404 Not Found error page will be rendered.

Visual Studio is simply hampering you by trying to detect and prevent all unhandled exceptions.

Comment: thanks, I tried setting it to 'release' mode but still get the error.

Comment: Are you starting the debugger (F5/play button) or simply compiling and accessing your site? Have you tried deploying to IIS?